# Delegating constructor issue - Is it safe?

Tags: c++, constructor

This [code](http://ideone.com/NkzUAo) is calling another ctor in one ctor:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class F {
public:
    F() { cout << "ctor1\n"; }
    F(int) { cout << "ctor2\n"; }
    ~F() { cout << "dtor\n"; }
};
class Foo {
    F f;
public:
    Foo() : f() { cout << "1\n"; }
    Foo(int i) : f(i) { Foo(); cout << "2\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Foo object(1); 
    return 0;
}
```

The result is:

```
ctor2
ctor1
1
dtor
2
dtor
```

It seems the member variable `f` destroyed twice here, is it Okay?

Comment: Additionally to Anton's answer, I dont see why "ctor2" is being printed. I think this should be ctor1 http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bc8d4be86a5ccebf

Comment: @user2950911 Sorry, I confused the version of the code. Code has been fixed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here

```
Foo(int i) { Foo(); cout << "2\n"; }
```

You are not using delegating constructor. What you're doing is creating a temporary instance of `Foo` in the constructor body (and destroying it immediately).

The correct syntax for delegating constructor is

```
Foo(int i) : Foo() { cout << "2\n"; }
```